# How to run substring on the message field of Get-Winevent

Tags: powershell, substring

This is the PowerShell query I'm starting with:

```
$CRM_Serverlist = 'Server-114', 'Server-115', 'Server-118', 'Server-P119'
$CRM_Account = 'domain\svcCRM'
$svcCRM_cred = Get-Credential -Credential $CRM_Account
ForEach ($CRM_Server in $CRM_Serverlist) {
   Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $CRM_Server -Credential $svcCRM_cred -FilterHashtable @{
       LogName = 'Application'
       ProviderName='MSCRMPlatform'
       Level = 3 # 1 Critical, 2 Error, 3 Warning, 4 Information
       } | select-object message | Format-List -Property message
   }
```

It produces output like similar to this.  (I've truncate the SQL queries for brevity.)

```
Message : Query execution time of 14.6 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 283; 
          Database: CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects ...

Message : Query execution time of 10.9 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 54; Database: 
          CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: select "a360_connectionrule0".a360_ConnectionId ...
    
Message : Query execution time of 19.3 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 272; 
          Database: CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: WITH "incident0Security" as (...
    
Message : Query execution time of 53.6 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 276; 
          Database: CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: select "incident0".a360_EscalationDate2...
```

What I want to do is extract the time from all the messages from all the servers, sort by the time so that the longest running SQL statements are listed first, then output them for so they can be tuned to run faster.  Outputting the time would be nice but is not strictly required.
It would be great if I could end up with something like this:

```
Time: 53.6
Message : Query execution time of 53.6 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 276; 
          Database: CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: select "incident0".a360_EscalationDate2...

Time: 19.3
Message : Query execution time of 19.3 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 272; 
          Database: CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: WITH "incident0Security" as (...

Time: 14.6
Message : Query execution time of 14.6 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 283; 
          Database: CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects ...

Time: 10.9
Message : Query execution time of 10.9 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 54; Database: 
          CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1; Query: select "a360_connectionrule0".a360_ConnectionId ...
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `EventLogRecord` instances have a `Properties` property and normally you can find values by index without needing to parse the `Message` via regex. Try it with one event of these, inspect this `Properties` property and see if the time appearing in the `Message` is there. If not, you can also try `.ToXml()`, as last resource you will need to extract it via regex which doesn't seem that hard but imo, is better to avoid when there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: I apologize for being such a newbie but:  How do I see those Properties?

Comment: I did this and I believe it gave me what I need:    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $CRM_Server -Credential $svcCRM_cred -FilterHashtable @{
      LogName = 'Application'
      ProviderName='MSCRMPlatform'
      Level = 3 # 1 Critical, 2 Error, 3 Warning, 4 Information
      } | Get-Member

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how you can check this

Comment: Running:
  $evt = Get-WinEvent ... -Maxevents 1
  $evt.Properties 
gave the following output:
Value
-----
10.1
10
88
CRM_MSCRM; Server:Server-SQL1  
WITH "incident0Security" as (...

The above was for a SQL Query that took 10.1 seconds.  Thanks very much for your help - I've gotten the time data I need without having to parse through the contents of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work however as stated in comments, it would be a better idea to not do it via regex and try looking into the [`Properties` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.properties?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-diagnostics-eventing-reader-eventlogrecord-properties) of the [`EventLogRecord` objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to see if the execution time value is there.

```bash
$re = [regex] '(?<=Query execution time of )[\d.]+'

$CRM_Serverlist | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -Credential $svcCRM_cred -FilterHashtable @{
        LogName      = 'Application'
        ProviderName = 'MSCRMPlatform'
        Level        = 3 # 1 Critical, 2 Error, 3 Warning, 4 Information
    }
} |
Select-Object @{
    Name       = 'Time'
    Expression = { [timespan]::FromSeconds($re.Match($_.Message).Value) }
}, Message | Sort-Object Time -Descending
```

---

How to know if you can get the *execution time* by looking into the `Properties` property of one of the events:

1. Pick one event from one of your servers:

```
$evt = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName pickOneServer -Credential $cred -FilterHashtable @{
    LogName      = 'Application'
    ProviderName = 'MSCRMPlatform'
    Level        = 3 # 1 Critical, 2 Error, 3 Warning, 4 Information
} -MaxEvents 1
```

2. Inspect it's `Properties` property:

```
$evt.Properties
```

If you see the decimal value for elapsed time here, then you can pick it by index, for example let's say the elapsed time is in **index 2**:

```
$evt.Properties.Value[1] # since index starts in 0 in pwsh
```

3. Then assuming we could find this value there, the whole script would change to this instead of using *regex* to pick the value:

```
$CRM_Serverlist | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -Credential $svcCRM_cred -FilterHashtable @{
        LogName      = 'Application'
        ProviderName = 'MSCRMPlatform'
        Level        = 3 # 1 Critical, 2 Error, 3 Warning, 4 Information
    }
} | Select-Object @{
    Name       = 'Time'
    Expression = { [timespan]::FromSeconds($_.Properties.Value[1]) }
}, Message | Sort-Object Time -Descending
```